# Get odd/even records from MS access database into Visual Basic 2008

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Can I ask how do I filter the records in my database based on its row position?

For example I have the following data in a field "Date/Time":

> Date/Time
>
> 9/9/2009 05:45am
>
> 9/9/2009 7:00am
>
> 9/10/2009 6:00am
>
> 9/10/2009 5:00pm

I need to insert the odd number of records in a new table field "Login"
and I also need to store the even records into the field "Logout"

Here is the expected output:

> Login   ...................            |         Logout
>
> 9/9/2009 05:45am  |  9/9/2009 7:00am
>
> 9/10/2009 6:00am  |  9/10/2009 5:00pm

Comment: Is there an AutoNumber field in the table?  If so, you could use SQL like the following:
SELECT tblA.MyAutoNum, TblA.MyDate, TblA_1.MyDate
FROM TblA, TblA AS TblA_1
WHERE (((([TblA]![MyAutoNum] Mod 2))=1) AND ((TblA_1.MyAutoNum)=[TblA]![MyAutoNum]+1));

Comment: How come your not saving the data this way now?

Comment: I think there needs to be a field that sez "Login " or "Logout", to account for missing Logouts when it crashes or someone quits without doing Logout.